Can distinct elements in a random sub-sample be an indicator of distinct elements in the population?
We have a sequence of elements $D = <a_1,a_2,...a_m>$. Let $a_i$ come from $[n]$. Our goal is to estimate the number of distinct elements in $D$.
We use a simple idea. We have a set $B=${} and we pass through the sequence and add an element $a_i$ to the set $B=$ with probability $p$. And as per this lecture  , $\frac{|B|}{p}$ is a good estimator for distinct elements in $D$.
I would like to prove this statement formally.
I can prove a similar estimator for the cardinality of $D$.
If $B$ was a multi-set or a tuple, i.e., repeated elements appear distinctly. Then $\frac{|B|}{p}$ is an estimator for $|D|$.
\begin{align}
E[|B|] &= \sum_{i \in [m]}1 \cdot P(a_i \text{ being in B}) \\
&= |D|p 
\end{align}
Hence,
$$|D| = \frac{E[|B|]}{p}$$
But I do not see how this argument works formally for unique elements?
